# Riemannian metric on the cotangent bundle

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I have been trying to define the Levi-Civita connection by directly constructing a Riemannian metric on the cotangent bundle (I know once you have Levi-Civita, this is possible, but I want to do it the other way). I have an idea for a metric on the cotangent bundle, but I cannot prove it is positive definite.

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Define $H : T^*M\to\mathbb{R}$ the function
$$H(v^{\#}) = \frac{1}{2}||v^{\#}||^2.$$

Then the symplectic structure on $T^*M$ gives rise to a vector field $X_H$ whose flows are the geodesic flow. Define $g'$ a $(2,0)$-tensor on $T^*M$ as
$$g'(v, w) = g(D\pi(v), D\pi(w)) + g(D\pi(\mathcal{L}_{X_H}(v)), D\pi(\mathcal{L}_{X_H}(w))),$$
where $\pi : T^*M\to M$ is the projection and $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lie derivative.

Is this $g'$ a Riemannian metric?

Comment: I assume the $\mathcal L_{X_V}$ is a typo?

Comment: In addition to Ted Shifrin's comment, it's unclear whether in the second term you mean $D\pi(\mathcal{L}_{X_H}(v))$ (in which case, what does $\mathcal{L}_{X_H}(v)$ mean, since $v$ is not a vector field) or $D\pi(\mathcal{L}_{X_H})(v)$ (in which case, what does $D\pi(\mathcal{L}_{X_H})$ mean).

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah yes!

Comment: @user17945 Ah, it seems I have greatly confused myself. Alas